# Ternary operator + C++11 constructor from initializer_list

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, ternary-operator, initializer-list

While developing an application, I had the following problem. I wanted to return an empty `std::list<string>` when a given function pointer was null, or the result of that function otherwise. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> (*ParamGenerator)();

std::list<std::string> foo() {
    /* ... */
    ParamGenerator generator = ...;
    if(generator)
        return generator();
    else
        return {};
}
```

However, I usually like to use the ternary (`?:`) operator in these cases, so I tried using it this way (as usual):

```
return generator ? generator() : {};
```

But got this error:

```
somefile.cpp:143:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
somefile.cpp:143:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

Does this mean I can't use the ternary operator to return objects created using their constructor from an `initializer_list`? Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: My advice would be: **don't do this at all**. Make it a generic algorithm that takes an iterator (whose type is a template parameter) so when you realize `std::list` was a bad choice, you can change to something else relatively painlessly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'll probably take that advice ;). I'd like to know if it is possible anyway(or why it isn't it case it can't be done).

Comment: Okay, fair enough. It is an interesting question (for which I up-voted) even though I think the exact application probably isn't the best.

Comment: Actually, now that i think about it, i can't template this function. That function is actually an export from a shared object, so i need to know the return type during compilation. I agree that on a different context, a templated solution would be better.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Standard writes in 8.5.4.1: List-initialization

> Note: List-initialization can be used
>
> - as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
> - as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)
> - in a return statement (6.6.3)
> - as a function argument (5.2.2)
> - as a subscript (5.2.1)
> - as an argument to a constructor invocation (8.5, 5.2.3)
> - as an initializer for a non-static data member (9.2)
> - in a mem-initializer (12.6.2)
> - on the right-hand side of an assignment (5.17)

Nothing of them is a ternary operator. The more minimalistic `return 1?{}:{};` is invalid too, what you want is impossible.

Of course you can explicitly call the constructor `std::list<std::string>{}`, but I would recommend to write out the `if`-`else`-block as you already did.

Comment: Great, that was the justification i was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

When you do `{}` the compiler has no knowledge of the type you are expecting, so it's just a meaningless expression that the compiler doesn't know what to do with. Both sides of the `:` are evaluated separately, and only then will the compiler complain if the types don't match. I would just do this:

```
return generator ? generator() : std::list<std::string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really like the ternary operator, you can try something like this:

`return generator ? generator() : decltype(generator()) { "default value", "generator was empry" };`

it will work even if you change the return types later.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to define a wrapper function for the conditional operator:

```
template<class T> T& conditional(bool b, T&x, T&y) { return b ? x : y; }
template<class T> const T& conditional(bool b, const T&x, const T&y) { return b ? x : y; }
```

That allows you to call:

```
return conditional(generator, generator(), {});
```